# Clear the unkown matrix Y from the equation

Tags: matrices

I have the following matrix equation:

$\overline{\textbf{s}} = \overline{\textbf{V}}  \overline{\textbf{i}}^*$ and $\overline{\textbf{i}} = \overline{\textbf{Y}}\overline{\textbf{v}}$

therefore:

$\overline{\textbf{s}} = \overline{\textbf{V}}  ({\overline{\textbf{Y}}\overline{\textbf{v}})^*}$

$\overline{\textbf{s}}$ is a complex vector,
$\overline{\textbf{i}}$ is a complex vector,
$\overline{\textbf{v}}$ is a complex vector,
$\overline{\textbf{V}}$ is a diagonal complex matrix which diagonal elements are $\overline{\textbf{v}}$, and
$\overline{\textbf{Y}}$ is the complex matrix I need to clear. (Everything but $\overline{\textbf{Y}}$  is known).

It's been a while since I left the university and I am not entirely sure if this is correct:

$\overline{\textbf{v}}(\overline{\textbf{s}}  \overline{\textbf{V}} )^*=  \overline{\textbf{Y}}$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's $x$? If that's meant to be multiplication, just skip it. Multiplication is implied.

Comment: Also, what is $^\ast$? If it's just complex conjugation, then it simply carries into both components of the product. If it's meant to be complex conjugation + matrix tranpose, then this makes no sense because you get multiplication of a matrix with a row vector.

Comment: The formula is standard and is the Power FLow equation for AC electrical circuits, so I'm not making it up.

Comment: Oh right, engineering notation, probably include jmaginary numbers. In that case it's probably just complex conjugation of a vector, no tranpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $^\ast$ just conjugates, you simply have

$${\bf s}=V(Y{\bf v})^\ast=VY^{\ast}{\bf v}^\ast$$

However, you can't extract a matrix if you only know the action on a single vector. You need to know what it does to at least the same number of vectors as the dimension of the matrix is, before you can extract the matrix.

Comment: What do you mean? s,V avd v are known, should I know something elese? the unknown is Y.

Comment: Yes, but $s$ and $v$ are only vectors. Even when you observe ${\bf i}=Y{\bf v}$, there are infinitely many matrices $Y$ that create *the same* ${\bf i}$ from a given ${\bf v}$. You see the problem? You have $n$ components of a vector and looking for $n^2$ components of a matrix. Not enough information!

Comment: mmm Thanks, this proposition was made in an electrical forum, and it didn't make quite sense to me. now I know it cannot be solved, because another property of Y is that it has to be symmetric. (I don't know if that makes any difference)

Comment: Symmetry is not enough, there are still $n(n+1)/2$ components to calculate. You need to "test" your circuit with different combination of voltages on the input to really know what it does.

Comment: The idea was basically to reverse engeneer a commercial solver by its results, because the composition of the Y matrix is where all the modelling load is. Good to know.

Comment: For a matrix of dimension $n$, test $n$ linearly indepenedent vectors $v_i$ and put them into columns of a new matrix $W$. The same way, you put the corresponding vectors $s_i$ ($i=1..n$) into a matrix $S$. Then you have a matrix equation $S=VY^\ast W^\ast$ which you can invert (if $V$ is invertible): $Y=V^{-1\ast} S^{\ast}W^{-1}$.